# Warning during compilation and its slowing down (security risk)

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, compilation-error, miktex-update, security

after upgrading to MiKTeX 20.11 (Texmaker 4.5) I've found an error in Message/Log block:

`: security risk: running with elevated privileges`

**The main problem is that there is a significant slowdown during the initial compilation** (I use `pdflatex`). With the increasing complexity of compilation (more packages, configuration), the translation will be significantly extended, even to 1-2 minutes.

I note that this was not the case with previous versions and everything happened with the upgrade to the new version of MikTeX. Using the console, I performed a complete upgrade of all packages. I also repeatedly installed MikTex and TexMaker. But without success...

Using the following link, I added a flag to the configuration for merging pdflatex:
https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/212

But I'm not sure that this solution is right?!

Comment: ask in the miktex github (but with more details, for example how you installed miktex and where exactly you get the message).

Comment: I get the security warning all the time. I guess because I am running with administrator privileges.
I learned long ago not to trust MiKteX updates. I always do a fresh install, after changing the old directories names. That way I can go back to a tested configuration. It happens many times that a new version of MiKTeX has bugs or some package clash with another. I never experienced slowdowns with pdflatex due to an upgrade, but sometimes it is better to wait before upgrading until it gets stable.